# Retrofit2 Dynamically change endpoint

Tags: android, retrofit2, endpoint

Is it possible to dynamically change an endpoint.
I have the following code which is working.
Now I want to use the same function,  and depending of some parameters the endpoint changes to /api/v1/contents. 
Changing "/api/v1/contents_dev" to "/api/v1/contents" dynamically.

```
@GET("/api/v1/contents_dev")
    fun cmsContents(
        @Query("fields") fields: String,
        @Query("ids") ids: String,
        @Query("filters") filters: String
    ): Observable<ContentsDevModel>

    fun getCmsContents(
        context: Context,
        observer: Observer<ContentsDevModel>
    ): Subscription {
        return create(context)
            .cmsContents(
                "linkType.linkUrl,image",
                "89746946",
                "rain"
            )
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(observer)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `@Path` annotation for that.

```
@GET("/api/v1/{thePath}")
fun cmsContents(
    @Path("thePath") path: String,
    @Query("fields") fields: String,
    @Query("ids") ids: String,
    @Query("filters") filters: String
): Observable<ContentsDevModel>
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try it and let you know the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

@GET("/api/users/{dynamic_params}")

public Call getUser(@Path("dynamic_params") String dynamic_params);

or if you can use @ url parameters

@GET

Call dynamicurl(@Url String url);